# Recursive Sine function

Tags: c++, function, recursion, trigonometry

I'm writing a sine function that has to be recursive. I have written a sine function but am not really sure how to do it recursively.  Could someone explain how to get started on this?

This is what I have so far:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
Name: sine( double X );

Return: Function "sine" will return the 
sine of X, where X is measured in radians.
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

double sine(double X)
{
  double result = 0;
  double term;
  int k;
  double lim;

  k = 0;
  lim = power(10, -8); 
  term = power(-1, k)*power(X, ((2*k) + 1)) / (factorial((2*k)+1));  
  result = term;
  while (absolute(term) > lim)  
  {
    k += 1;
    term = power(-1, k)*power(X, ((2*k) + 1)) / (factorial((2*k)+1));  
    result += term;
  }


  return result;
}
```

EDIT: I used a wrapper function to solve this.  Basically created another function called

```
double sine_rec(double X, double k)
```

and changed around the current code to fit in with that.

Comment: Is this homework? Because then I'd rather give you a hint than a complete answer and spoil the fun for you.

Comment: @Mads it has a homework tag....perhaps just added?

Comment: Have you tried Googling this? There seems to be plenty of examples out there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I would approach this would be to have another function `sine(double X, int n)` which takes another integer parameter - the number of terms to include in the power series approximation. Then this function could return something like `[nth term in series] + sine(X, n - 1)` (just remember a prior `if` statement to deal with n = 1).

Comment: I think this is what I did.  I used a wrapper function.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the `while` loop by recursion in following way:

```
double sine(double X, int k = 0)
{
  double result = 0;
  double term;
  double lim;

  lim = power(10, -8); 
  term = power(-1, k)*power(X, ((2*k) + 1)) / (factorial((2*k)+1));  
  if (absolute(term) > lim)  
  {
    return sine(X, k+1) + term; 
  }
  else
  {
    return term;
  }
}
```

But I cannot recommend doing this at all. (There are better solutions even to this recursion, but find them on your own)